# Nosqlunit-neo4j unable to assign label to Node in Spring Data Neo4j 4

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

It seems that Nosqlunit-neo4j is not compatible with SDN 4 since TypeRepresentationStrategy is removed. It adds the node defined in following graphml xml file into test database but doesn't assign it a label due to which repository.count() returns 0. However, if I query the database natively, then it does fetches the node without any Label.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<graphml xmlns="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns">
    <key id="__type__" for="node" attr.name="__type__" attr.type="string"></key>
    <key id="productId" for="node" attr.name="productId" attr.type="string"></key>

    <graph id="G" edgedefault="directed">
        <node id="3">
            <data key="__type__">com.my.package.Product</data>
            <data key="productId">100001235</data>
            <index name="__types__" key="className">com.my.package.Product
            </index>
        </node>
    </graph>
</graphml>
```

Does anyone facing the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the label `Product` directly it should work.
You don't need the index or the `__type__` properties anymore.

Comment: Can you show me an example? Because it didn't work when I added a "label" property in node element.

Comment: If I use json format (SpringTemplateInsertionStrateygy and SpringTemplateComparisonStrategy) then it throws exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/neo4j/support/Neo4jTemplate since support package is not available in sdn 4